# Show that $(a_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

We have $(a_{n})_{n\geq1}$ a sequence of real numbers such that $a_{n}^{2}>a_{n+1}^{2}$ and $a_{n+1}^{3}+a_{n}^{3}>1$, for every $n\geq1$. Show that $(a_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is convergent.
I tried taking case by case for signs of terms and monotony but I feel like it is another method for that problem.

Comment: If you could show $(a_n)$ is bounded below by zero, that would do it since the first condition gives the sequence is decreasing (assuming positive values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that at some point $a_n$ is a negative number, let $a_n=-y$. We will call $x=a_{n+1}$ for this case. Clearly $x>0$ because of the second condition, so
$$
x^3-y^3>1\implies x^3>y^3+1>y^3\implies x^2>y^2
$$
which contradicts our first condition. As such our sequence must be bounded below by $0$.

The first condition shows that our sequence is decreasing, and since it is also bounded below by $0$, it must be convergent. Q.E.D.